# Overriding a field of base Content Type in Sensenet 6.4

Tags: sensenet

My custom 'IPAProject' CTD is based on Workspace CTD.

If I override inherited Description field in the following way (lines omitted for brevity):

```
<ContentType name="IPAProject" parentType="Workspace" handler="SenseNet.ContentRepository.Workspaces.Workspace" xmlns="http://schemas.sensenet.com/SenseNet/ContentRepository/ContentTypeDefinition">
.
.
.
<Field name='Description' type='LongText'>
      <DisplayName>Custom DisplayName</DisplayName>
</Field>
.
.
.
</ContentType>
```

Will I lose existing data that I have recorded in the Description field for IPAProject?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. More detail: data will not be changed.